# NPE on ProgressBar

Tags: java, android

I've got NullPointerException everytime I want to change visibility of progressbar. It's working with any other layout item but this. I've got also two text views initialized the same way, but they are working. Do you know what is the problem?

Fragment code:

```
@BindView(R.id.progress_indicator) ProgressBar mProgressBar;

@Override
public void setLoadingIndicator(boolean active) {
    if (getView() == null) {
        return;
    }

    if(active) {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progress_indicator"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/thisWeekOnDuty"
    android:layout_marginEnd="152dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="152dp"
    android:indeterminate="true" />
```

Stacktrace:

```
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {pl.rasztabiga.klasa1a/pl.rasztabiga.klasa1a.mainAct.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ProgressBar.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3444)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3484)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2747)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6176)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ProgressBar.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                        at pl.rasztabiga.klasa1a.mainAct.OnDutiesFragment.setLoadingIndicator(OnDutiesFragment.java:84)
                                                                        at pl.rasztabiga.klasa1a.mainAct.OnDutiesPresenter.onCreateLoader(OnDutiesPresenter.java:51)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl.createLoader(LoaderManager.java:539)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl.createAndInstallLoader(LoaderManager.java:548)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl.initLoader(LoaderManager.java:603)
                                                                        at pl.rasztabiga.klasa1a.mainAct.OnDutiesPresenter.start(OnDutiesPresenter.java:46)
                                                                        at pl.rasztabiga.klasa1a.mainAct.OnDutiesFragment.onResume(OnDutiesFragment.java:50)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:2133)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1156)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1295)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1277)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:2164)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchResume(FragmentController.java:223)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments(FragmentActivity.java:509)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(FragmentActivity.java:498)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onPostResume(AppCompatActivity.java:175)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6807)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3421)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3484) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2747) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6176) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
```

Comment: Not without a stack trace.

Comment: Add android:id="@+id/progress_indicator" in your xml <ProgressBar/> tag.

Comment: It is already there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try binding you view like this in `fragment`:

```
 @Override 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        // TODO Use fields...
        return view;
      }
}
```

see this http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/  for NON-ACTIVITY BINDING

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling `ButterKnife.bind(this);` in your activity's onCreate?

I'd need much more info before being able to properly debug this.

Comment: Yes, I call ButterKnife.bind(getActivity());
Whole fragment code: http://pastebin.com/qLX7vn8d